# Entropy of a non isolated system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, heat-engine

I'm trying to self study thermodynamics. I've stumbled upon a problem on my textbook (which is italian by the way):

> a real thermal machine based on a Carnot's cycle works between two
> sources of temperature $520 \mathrm{K}$ and $1300 \mathrm{K}$. This
> machine has an efficency equal to $25\%$ of the ideal efficency. Every
> cycle the machine draws $500 \mathrm{J}$ from the hot source.
> -> Calculate the variation of ambient's entropy each cycle;
> -> Calculate the variation of universe's entropy each cycle;
> [Results: $0.433 \mathrm{J K^{-1}}$ and $0.433 \mathrm{J K^{-1}}$]

Now I'm quite stuck with this one. I managed to reach the desired result by calculating the ambient entropy variation as the opposite of the entropy variation of the system during a cycle. Even if the result is correct I think the reasoning is wrong. The machine is said to be real, thus not reversible, therefore the variation of entropy of the ambient should be greater of the module of the variation of entropy of the system:

$$ \Delta S_{ambient} > |\Delta S_{system}| $$

Thus using the numbers provided by the problem there should hold $\Delta S_{ambient} > 0.433 \mathrm{J K^{-1}}$. I thought that to calculate the actual value of $\Delta S_{ambient}$ I could impose the machine to be ideal, thus the efficency is the maximum one and can be calculated as the efficency of a Carnot's machine: $\eta^{(max)} = {\Delta T \over T_2}$. By this reasoning I could calculate the entropy variation of the system when considered ideal and impose the equality:

$$ \Delta S_{ambient} = |\Delta S_{system}^{(ideal)}| = - \Delta S_{system}^{(ideal)} $$

henceforth:

$$ \Delta S_{system}^{(ideal)} = {Q_2 \over T_2} - {|Q_1| \over T_1} \Longleftrightarrow \eta^{(max)} = {\Delta T \over T_2} = 1 - {|Q_1| \over Q_2} \Longrightarrow |Q_1| = (1 - \eta^{(max)}) Q_2 $$

therefore it becomes:

$$ \Delta S_{system}^{(ideal)} = {Q_2 \over T_2} + {{(\eta^{(max)} - 1) Q_2} \over T_1}$$

which of course is zero because the entropy is defined moving from the Clausius inequality, which is zero when the cycle on which is calculated is reversible (thus ideal):

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n {\Delta Q_i \over T_i} \leq 0 \Longleftrightarrow \Delta S = S(B) - S(A) = \sum_{i=0}^n {\Delta Q_i \over T_i} |^{(reversible)}_{A \to B}$$

What am I getting wrong? Shouldn't the variation of entropy of the ambient be greater than the module of the one produced by the real machine? If this assertation is correct, where does my reasoning fail? Shouldn't the variation of entropy of the ambient be equal to the module of the one the machine produces? Therefore how can the entropy variation of the ambient be zero?

P.S. Thanks a lot in advance for your time and effort in answering me! Excuse my rudimental English: I'm still practising it.

Comment: No heat engine working in cycles can store entropy because it must return to its original state at the end of each cycle (and entropy is a state variable). Thus, the total entropy increase in the universe per cycle from running a real heat engine must occur in the ambient or surroundings—not inside the system or machine. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: This setup is characterized by an engine operating in a cycle, two thermal reservoirs, and two conductive resistances to heat transfer, each situated between the engine and one of the reservoirs.  All the entropy generation is assumed to occur within the resistances, which are considered part of the ambient surroundings.  The generated entropy change due to this generated entropy is transferred to the reservoirs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. @Chemomechanics, I almost understood. You are saying that on a cycle the entropy variation, because of it being a state function, should be always zero, right? But why am I able to get a non zero entropy variation when calculating it on the cycle of an isolated heat engine system? For instance, this is another problem of my textbook:

Comment: "A heat engine works between a source made of water mixed with ice and a source with boiling water. When the efficency is 0.100, the engine melts 500 mg of ice (latent heat of 334000 J/Kg). Calculate the variation of the two sources and of the system formed by the two sources for eavery cycle", the result is 0.133J/K.
Why even if I'm calculating the entropy on a cycle I don't get a zero value? Is the difference the same difference between isolated and non isolated systems? And if so, even if the system is isolated, shouldn't the entropy be $0$ on a cycle, because of its definition?

Comment: The heat engine doesn't include the sources. There are entropy variations in the sources, which are considered part of the surrounding environment

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's much clearer now